# ARM template deploying Diagnostics Settings does not enable Metrics logs

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-iot-hub, azure-diagnostics, azure-rm-template

I'm using Azure RM Template deployments with a Visual Studio 2017 Resource Group project to deploy IoTHub instance with diagnostics settings in Log Analytics.

The problem is with deployment of the Diagnostics Settings template and specifically with the `AllMetrics` category under the `metrics` property.

I'm following the instructions for deploying Diagnostics Settings as [Non-Compute resource template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-enable-diagnostic-logs-using-template#non-compute-resource-template)

The deployment completes successfully, but this one

```
{
      "type": "providers/diagnosticSettings",
      "name": "[concat('Microsoft.Insights/', parameters('iotHub.diagnostics.settingName'))]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Devices/IoTHubs', parameters('iotHub.name'))]"
      ],
      "apiVersion": "2017-05-01-preview",
      "properties": {
        "name": "[parameters('iotHub.diagnostics.settingName')]",
        "workspaceId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces', parameters('iotHub.diagnostics.logAnalyticsName'))]",
        "logs": [
          {
            "category": "Connections",
            "enabled": true,
            "retentionPolicy": {
              "days": 0,
              "enabled": false
            }
          }
        ],
        "metrics": [
          {
            "category": "AllMetrics",
            "enabled": true,
            
            "retentionPolicy": {
              "days": 0,
              "enabled": false
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

is not deployed as enabled - in the portal this is not checked as enabled. Tried multiple times, both as a new deployment and as an update.

[image]

If I go and manually enable this in the portal, then it stays enabled after consequent deployments of the same.

**The `diagnosticSettings` resource is nested under the IoTHub resource definition.**

Any ideas?

Comment: I dont see a way to enable it without specifying a "sink"? am I being thick?

Comment: the sink is specified as Log Analytics by the "workspaceId" property and it is relevant to both `logs` and `metrics`, see my update

Comment: oh, ok, my bad. sorry, this looks right (at least according to the docs). i'm afraid I havent done this and cannot help you :(

Answer (score 0):

```
"type": "providers/diagnosticSettings",
"name": "[concat(parameters('iotHub.name'), '/Microsoft.Insights/', parameters('settingName'))]",
```

the above change should work

Comment: I have not noted this in my question, but the quoted resource definition is actually a nested resource inside the IoTHub Resource definition.